# How to get last created file in a bucket using Google Cloud Storage Java SDK?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How do I get the last created file in a GCS bucket using Google Cloud Storage Java SDK?
Currently, I am using the `storage.list()` and iterating through all the files and thus getting the last created file.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage doesn't offer flexible querying of objects.  If you want to find objects based on some property, such as upload time, you should store that information in a database whenever an object created, updated, or delete. Then, you can just query the database to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a cloud function which copies any uploaded file to a fixed key (listen on the finalize GCS event), say key 1. Then your application just queries key 1.

Instead of copying the file you could also look at a peristent cache like Redis to store key 1.